# When restarting Ubuntu quit supervisor sooner than other services

Tags: systemd, supervisord

I have supervisor that is handling a queue process that is dependent on Redis being available. 
When I restart the server (Ubuntu 18.04) the Redis server is quitting before Supervisor and the queue process spams me with hundreds of errors in Slack because of the missing Redis server.

I need to set Supervisor quit before the other services that are used in the subprocesses of Supervisor so I do not get all these errors. I know it should be in the systemd but haven't done it so far and couldn't find a good way to find it in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`systemd` inverts the start order during stopping. I.e. if you have your `supervisor` service unit with `After=redis` then `supervisor` will be stopped before `redis` on shutdown. (Or alternatively add `Before=supervisor` to the `redis` service unit).

From `info systemd.unit`

> Before=, After=
>
> [...] Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. [...]